# RegEx stops working when placed into ValidationExpression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a text box where a user enters their email address.  I need to prevent people using certain email addresses, as this is for corporate (B2B) use.

Can anyone help me with the RegEx which would return false if email addresses contain @gmail or @yahoo?

So far I have this (thanks to @Sabuj) `@(yahoo|gmail)\.` but when placed into a RegularExpressionValidator it doesn't work:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression='@(yahoo|gmail)\.' runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_email" />
```

Having read MSDN for more info, I've also tried this but it still returns true regardless of the content entered:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression='^(@(yahoo|gmail)\.)$' runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_email"  />
```

Comment: *(Just a suggestion)* , Why don't you restrict user to use emails from specific domain? that list would be limited *(I guess)* and would prevent all other domains whether free or paid.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: Thanks for that Robin.  The expression seems to work when tested independently, but not when place into the ASP.Net control

Comment: @Habib, because we need to allow 99.99% of domains, but only refuse a certain few where spam tends to be sent from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with `^.*@(?!(yahoo|gmail)).*$`

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression="^.*@(?!(yahoo|gmail)).*$" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_email" Text="No free email accounts allowed" />
```

This will allow any text to pass the validator that *doesn't* contain `@yahoo` or `@gmail`.

Don't forget to check `Page.IsValid` in your code behind, and to include an `<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" />` in your `.aspx`.

Answer (score 2):

Since e-mail addresses have a complex syntax (more complex than most people realise, for instance, they can contain comments [RFC 822 § 3.4.3]), I'd suggest not using regex at all for this. Instead, use a "proper" e-mail parser, then ask the parser for the domain part of the address.

Comment: I'm already using a RegularExpressionValidator to check that the email address is in the correct format.  This is just a secondary check that will prevent abuse of the system

Comment: First of all; once again; I *really* don't recommend using regex for e-mail address validation (see http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). If you really want to use regex, then couldn't that first regex be written to do this validation as well?

Comment: Do you validate by pinging the address?  I see on Google most of the top-ranked verifiers are just RegEx's bundled under an interface.  Your link has prompted a lot of further thought however, so thank you for that

Comment: @EvilDr The last few times I've had to validate e-mail adresses I've used some module or other and not really cared much about its inner workings. I imagine a good module would not rely too much on regex, but might use it in part (the link in my previous comment should illustrate the complexity of doing it with regex *only* and it doesn't even work with comments). Probably a combination of regex and good old "programmed logic" is the way to go. Don't get me wrong I love regex, but its not the ultimate tool (or we wouldn't need programming languages), especially when parsing complex syntax.

Comment: @EvilDr The idea of "pinging" the address is certainly thrilling, but I've yet to use it in real life.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression=".*@(?!(yahoo|gmail)).*" ControlToValidate="txt_email" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Yahoo and Gmail disallowed"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The validation expression property should be set to match the entire string.

But my regex `.*@(?!(yahoo|gmail)).*` matches the whole email. So it works :)

You don't need `^` or `$` since the string is gonna be a single line.

Also don't forget to add `type="email"` to your `txt_email`. It will automatically take care of whether it is a valid email or not.

If the error msg appears, then it isn't valid, but if it doesn't appear, then it is absolutely valid.

Comment: Thanks but it appears to be working wrongly.  For example, `me@yahoo.com` is not allowed, but `me@mysite.com` is okay.  However your expression is working in reverse!

Comment: @EvilDr I'll send you snapshots.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my question wasn't clear enough.  `me@yahoo.com` should show **Hell** , but `me@mysite.com` should be okay!  Yahoo and GMail are the ones I am trying to block!

Comment: @EvilDr,can you plase tell me which ones do yoiu allow ?

Comment: Thanks that's got it.  Could you please just clarify what you mean by "matches the whole email", with a longer pattern rather than @SilverlightFox's short suggestion?

Comment: @EvilDr I believe the regular expression in this answer attempts to validate the email itself (e.g. allows `foo@example.com` but not `foo@foo@example.com`) whereas the one in my answer simply checks that it doesn't contain `@yahoo` or `@gmail` (`foo@example.com` and `foo@foo@example.com` allowed). My RegEx assumes that you will be validating the email address format itself separately and returns `No free email accounts allowed` only if it contains `@yahoo`/`@gmail` and not in the case of a completely invalid address (`foo@foo@example.com`).

Comment: @EvilDr Ha ha, I've talked myself out of the bounty :)

Comment: Yes sorry about that.  Your answer is actually the most suitable in my work as I already have a validator to check the format of the address, but @AmitJoki's answer adds some thorough checks that other people reading this in future might benefit from.  I was just looking if it was possible to split a bounty when you replied above.  Thanks anyway for a helpful contribution.

Comment: @EvilDr No problem! Don't forget to include `@SilverlightFox` so I see any future replies.

Comment: @EvilDr Although this RegExp won't allow `"Abc@def"@example.com` which is a [perfectly valid email address](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/) so maybe not that useful for others to benefit from?

Comment: Very good @SilverlightFox.  Your version actually works really well in my code couple with my original (very lengthy) email validator expression (that came from elsewhere).  You've been a big help - thank you.

Comment: @EvilDr check out my answer now. It is better and small

Comment: @EvilDr, accept my answer if you want both email validation as well as shortest regex

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to check whether the mentioned emails are containing or not:

```
@(gmail|yahoo|mailinator|guerrillamail|dispostable)\.
```

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason when that is set as the ValidationExpression value, the validator fails to work and simply returns true for **every** value entered (e.g. me@domain.com returns true).  This is the bit I can't figure out!

Comment: I do not know much about ASP. Does it require to have the regex to be inside the double quote(`"`)? Or Does it require to escape the character `@` of regex inside the String?